# Error including bibliography in tabular environment

Tags: tables, bibtex

When trying to include a list of references in a tabular environment I get the following error sourced from the .bbl file:

ERROR: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Is there an easy fix? An example is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author, A},
  journal = {Journal A},
  title = {MyBook A},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l` columns are like `\mbox` and can not take vertical display material like a list, use a `p` column, which is like `\parbox`, so replace `l` by `p{5cm}` or whatever you need, but a 1-column `tabular` does not serve much purpose, so simply removing the `tabular` would also work.